# After migration the custom Export excel is showing an error

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services

After upgrading from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 ,the custom Export All is displaying this error : **An error occurred while generating your excel file**, whereas the default Export to excel is working fine.
How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Do you see any errors in event log? Please provide more details on this custom export functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When we migrate SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, the custom code and site customizations in general are not to be overlooked in SharePoint migration planning.

After you set up the new SharePoint 2013 environment, you should deploy the custom solutions in the new SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: We have deployed the custom solution in SharePoint 2013 environment